# guild.id is undefined in guildCreate event

Tags: javascript, events, discord, discord.js

So I am having this problem that when I'm trying to console log the ID from the guild that my bot joined it says: `Bot has joined the server. ID: undefined`

Heres the code of the guildCreate event file:

```
module.exports = async (guild) => {
        console.log("Bot has joined the server. Saved to DB! ID: " + guild.id)    
}
```

I would appreciate it when someone helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you handling events? It may be that you are not passing in `guild` as a parameter when calling the function. Try doing a console log to make sure that the guild parameter is being passed to the function. If `guild` is undefined, then you are likely calling the function without passing any parameters or giving it the wrong ones.

Comment: @cypher you should post an answer of how you resolved this, or delete your question.